# Problems deploying javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory in Weblogic 12c

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, war, weblogic12c, javax.xml

I'm trying deploy a web application (.war format) in Weblogic 12c. 
When I try deploy it, Weblogic throws the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLInputFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
Error weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLInputFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
```

I have read too many threads and "solutions" about this error, but none served me.

This is my weblogic.xml:

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <context-root>appName</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
    <resource-description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/testdb</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>jdbc/testdb</jndi-name>
    </resource-description>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

And these are my dependencies in pom.xml:

```
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Could you assist me in troubleshooting this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by explicitly excluding the *stax-api* dependency that is transitively pulled in by *spring-ws-core*. Try the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
      <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

You then just need to make sure that there are no other XML parsing issues when using the application.

HTH,
Ben